# .Net RIA Services: Javascript callback forces full reload of the application

Tags: silverlight-2.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

I've successfully implemented a Javascript call from Silverlight (i'm calling a java applet).
When the user finishes using the applet, I'd like to send the data back to Silverlight;
so I've created a callback function:

```
    [ScriptableMember]
    public void DoCallback(string svalue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s, "Value from Applet:", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Everything works fine, until the DoCallback() function ends - here for some reason the whole Silverlight application shuts down, and App.xaml.cs loads up from the beginning.

The function is implemented in a sub-View: ~/View/Applet.xaml.
I guess somehow the application don't get the /#/Applet parameter for the URI, that's why it forces a full reload..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...never use the html **button** instead of input[@type="button"] in a Silverlight project, because it will always submit like input[@type="submit"].